# Randomize Proportional

Tags: transforms

I'm trying to make a donut from the Blender Tutorials and I came across an issue I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I followed all the instructions from "Bender Goru" on Youtube.

Whenever I try to the randomize tool with proportionate (O),  it doesn't randomize the whole donut to give off that incing feeling around the donut. And I'm saying if randomize doesn't work now what's the point!!

Only one side goes down and if I select all. All of it will go down without curves.

[image]